# ng-show not working in datatables columns

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-datatables

I am creating a table in angular using datatables. I've use a value from the scope and I compare this value with the data received.

```
"columns": [{ data: null, render: function ( data, type, row ) {
var roleid =angular.element('#TextkeysController').scope().currentRole;
return '<p ng-show="'+data.id+' == '+roleid+'" class="btn btn-success btn-xs disabled" value="connected" >connected</p><p ng-show="'+data.id+' != '+roleid+'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" value="notConnected" ng-click="connectRole(\''+data.id+'\',\''+data.name+'\')">Not connected</p>';
}, name: 'connect', "className":"center"}]
```

When I load the data both button appear in the row - column and the condition only apply when I click in a ng-click action.

Could someone help me to know why this happen?

Answer (score 2):

Obviously angular is not aware of the HTML injected by dataTables. In this cases I use to `$compile` the rendered content in a `drawCallback` :

```
withOption('drawCallback', function() {
   $scope.$apply($compile(angular.element('#tableId'))($scope))
}
```

where `#tableId` is the `id` of your table. But in general this is a little bit messed up, imho. When I need specific angular directives attached to dataTables rows or columns I render the angular way with `datatable="ng"`. Slower but more clean and maintainable.

Comment: Should I add the withOption into the datatables javascript file or in the controller?

Comment: hey @jValls I was guessing you are using angular dataTables (thats why I retagged) - the above is the angular dataTables way, which I _strongly_  recommend. If you are using  jQuery dataTables without the directives, you should include [drawCallback as in the documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback).

Comment: I've solved the issue adding a condition directly and not using ng-show. However thanks for your help.

Comment: @jValls, OK, thank you for the upvote! Actually I would have recommended that, the small markup snippet indicated that you could do it by a simple ternary, but could not be sure since `roleid` perhaps could change dynamically, and that was the whole point? But I am using dataTables and angular dataTables really heavily over many projects, and I will say : click-events, go dataTables rendering. If you really _need_ angular directives, for example I use `ng-class` a lot where `$scope` variables determines the class, go `datatable="ng"` see https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/angularWay

Comment: @jValls anychance can you post the solution?