# How to render angular ng if/show within database

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatables

current I am working with a combination of datatables + angularjs. I'm following documentation here. https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/gettingStarted

My table is rendering and getting populated with angularjs code. The issue I am coming across is I only want the photo text to appear only when it exist. When I inspect the element, ng-hide is always set. It'll appear fine if I remove ng-if.

Code

```
<table datatable="ng" class="contact-grid-table row-border" dt-options="vm.dtOptions2" dt-column-defs="vm.dtColumnDefs" dt-instance="dtInstanceCallback" id="tableId">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Photo</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="contact in vm.contacts">
            <td>{{contact.firstName}}</td>
            <td>{{contact.lastName}}</td>
            <td><span ng-if="contact.photo">{{contact.photo}}</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I also tried the suggestion here [ng-show not working in datatables columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38657552/ng-show-not-working-in-datatables-columns) but my table will no longer load. Page just freezes.

May I ask if there's any suggestions on how to get ng-if/show to work with datatables.

```
vm.dtOptions2 = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
    .withOption('createdRow', function (row, data, dataIndex) {
        // Recompiling so we can bind Angular directive to the DT
        $compile(angular.element(row).contents())($scope);
    })
    .withOption('headerCallback', function (header) {
        if (!vm.headerCompiled) {
            // Use this headerCompiled field to only compile header once
            vm.headerCompiled = true;
            $compile(angular.element(header).contents())($scope);
        }
    })
    .withPaginationType('full_numbers').withOption('responsive', true)
    .withColReorder()
    .withColReorderOrder([0,1, 2,3])
    .withScroller()
    .withOption('bFilter', false) // for search box
    .withOption('bInfo', false) // for showing counts at the bottom
    .withOption('deferRender', true)
    .withOption('scrollY', 200)
    // Set order
    // Fix last right column
    .withDisplayLength(2)
    .withFixedHeader({
        bottom: false
    });
```

Comment: Please explain more.
The error is not clear now

Comment: What is the value of `contact.photo`? Is it undefined, null or an empty string?

Comment: Show in ng-if for null,undefined,empty => false    ,                     

Show in ng-show for null,undefined,empty => false     ,                                

Show in ng-hide for null,undefined,empty => true

Comment: @SalmanLaei  the value for contact.photo is a string. It has a value. But it still won't appear. It never renders in the UI, that's the problem I am coming across.

Comment: Try to create a minimal reproduction of this so we can look into it

Comment: Just to confirm if I'm on the right track here: https://codepen.io/timur_kh/pen/NWxQvbW does this pen look like your problem statement?

Comment: @timur very close! The only thing different from mine is I have withOptions. If I remove options it renders completely fine but I am trying not to. I posted my options above

Comment: right. so i updated the pen with your `withOptions` - and so far `ng-if` seems to work as it should. I think it is possible that these callbacks mess your DOM up but I can't seem to get them activated to verify. (do both callbacks need `$scope.$apply()`? ). Or better can you repro the issue on my codepen?

Comment: If you create a snippet I'll gladly take a look.